# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment (p5js)

Tags: javascript, p5.js

librarie: p5js

ERROR: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment (line 45)

line 45: if(x >= 0 && y = 600){

```
function lines(){
  strokeWeight(5);
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  let LoopingTrigger = false; //by default is false (Starts out of canvas)
  let x = -100; // width -100 || 100 on left of width
  let y = 700; // height +100 || 100 on bottom of height
  line(0, 0, x, 0);
  line(0, 0, 0, y);
  line(x, 0, x, y);
  line(0, y, x, y);
  ***if(x >= 0 && y = 600){***
    LoopingTrigger = true; // when in the canvas changes to true
  } else {
    LoopingTrigger = false;
  }
  while(LoopingTrigger){
    x = width + 1;
    y = height -1;
    line(0, 0, x, 0);
    line(0, 0, 0, y);
    line(x, 0, x, y);
    line(0, y, x, y);
  }
```

Comment: `y = 600` assigns 600 to y, is that what you want? or did you mean `y === 600` to test if y is 600?

Comment: also, your while loop will either never run, or run forever ... since LoopingTrigger never can change inside the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has several problems.
The error is because `&&` operator has higher priority than `=` operator and `x >= 0 && y` is not a variable.
You should edit your code `x >= 0 && y == 600` or `x >= 0 && (y = 600)`.

By the way, the `LoopingTrigger` variable is never changing in the `while` statement, so it iterates forever.